# How to mount an audio CD on a USB drive

Tags: sound, usb

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10 and I have a USB CD drive. I want to play an audio CD on that drive. I  know it's pretty simple to do, but I can't quite get it all together.  How can I do it?

Comment: Putting the CD in the drive doesn’t trigger a “What would you like to do?” prompt? 

Comment: My own cheap USB DVD player would not be recognized by the system no matter what I did...until I rebooted with the device attached. Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: @matigo The OP has one here, but not everyone has a desktop envoirnment. I, for example, might have a server with a CD reader and speakers, but no GUI. So in theory, there should be a command-line way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Audio CDs aren't really "mounted"... Their behavior is different.
If you ever get your system to recognize yours, you will see that the device is visible, but you will so no evidence of "mounting" (in df, nor gparted, nor mount, nor disks, etc)...

First I would ask are you sure that the desktop or your file browser doesn't have a CD icon for you to click on to browse the CD??? As far as I can tell this solution will just get you to that point. Your question states getting it "mounted". (There would be no need to do any of this if your CD is being recognized and you just need to download a music player...)

It's hard to just tell you what you need to access, when the command needs an output from what you are not able to see on your system without the CD being "mounted", for lack of the correct term....

But I will explain what I did:

I plugged my DVD drive in and inserted a CD.

I got the icon that for the CD on my desktop and the CD contents in the file browser.

I got my DVD drive device name from running `lsscsi` in a terminal... **mine was /dev/sr0** (I could have just looked at the gnome-disks application, that also listed it)

As the user (not root), in a terminal I ran `gio mount -l /dev/sr0`... which gave me the virtual mount point:

```
Drive(4): Slimtype eBAU108 5 L
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyvolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(0): Audio Disc
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitirUDisks2)
    Mount(0): Audio Disc -> cdda://sr0/
```

In the file browser I right-clicked and "unmounted" the CD.

**...So at this point I am believing I am where you are stuck.**

Now I have no icon on the desktop.

In the terminal (as the user), I am able to run `gio mount cdda://sr0/` and my dvd drive starts to spin and puts the icon back on my desktop... from which I can now navigate the CD contents.
*(I am also beginning to think `gio mount cdda://cdrom` may work too, so you may be able to bypass most of what I wrote above.. but I will leave it for context)*

If I want to view the contents in the terminal, I run `gio tree cdda://sr0/`

Unmounting (if you cared) would be `gio mount -u cdda://sr0`.... (or **cdda://cdrom** depending on which one you used)

In my opinion this is a last measure for a system that for whatever reason will never cooperate. There is probably a GUI somewhere that already does this. This is a bit cumbersome, especially for a function that should happen automatically on insertion.